# How to optimize two cycles with finding vector length?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, vector

Got such functions, that delete's some points from Curve, if it's too close to the Line (its straight line). But the point is the amount of coordinates. One Curve can have about 1000 coordinates, and it makes program works for 3-4 times slower.

Start Index and End index is needed for not checking all the straight line (amount of coordinates is about 3000)

```
(List<int>, List<int>) LineCheck(List<int> Xcurve, List<int> Ycurve, List<int> XLine, List<int> YLine, double deviation)
        {
            //point - координаты точки для проверки, LineUp - список координат верхней прямой
            //LineDown - список координат нижней прямой
            List<int> returnCurveX = new List<int>();
            List<int> returnCurveY = new List<int>();
            //отклонение от прямой, для большей точности проверки можно уменьшить
            //но надо проверять по факту

            for (int i = 0; i < Xcurve.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                bool flag = true;
                int XStartIndex = XLine.Where(w => w >= Xcurve[0]).First();
                int XEndIndex = XLine.Where(w => w <= Xcurve[Xcurve.Count - 1]).Last();

                for (int j = XStartIndex; j < XEndIndex; j++)
                {
                    double[] vector1 = { Xcurve[i] - XLine[j], Ycurve[i] - YLine[j] };
                    // Вычисление длин векторов
                    double length1 = Math.Sqrt(vector1[0] * vector1[0] + vector1[1] * vector1[1]);
                    if (length1 < deviation)
                    {
                        flag = false;


                    }

                }
                if (flag)

                {
                    returnCurveX.Add(Xcurve[i]);
                    returnCurveY.Add(Ycurve[i]);
                    //принадлежит прямой
                }
            }

           // return (Xcurve, Ycurve);
            //точка не попала на координаты прямой
            return (returnCurveX, returnCurveY);


        }
```

I've tried to break somehow the first cycle, but it don't allow me to return needed points. If we could change source array, maybe it would be easier.

Comment: If you have a straight line, why do you have a *collection* - `List<int> XLine` and `List<int> YLine`? Can we guarantee, that both `XLine` and `YLine` have just **2** items?

Comment: Yes, it's just X and Y coordinates of Line points. In Enter we've got X and Y of Curve, and X and Y of straight Line. we've got list because it can go with some angle.

Comment: I don't see the point of what you are doing here with XLine/YLine. You surely want to delete any point from the set of points on the curve that can be predicted (to within some acceptable tolerance) from its immediate neighbours. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about, or even what kind of data you are working with. A sequence of straight line segments are typically called a *polyline* (or polygon if closed). If you want to simplify a polyline, see [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

Comment: If you are worried about performance you should include measurements and related data. The major performance gains are typically done by reducing the total amount of work done, not micro optimizing some specific operation.

Comment: @MartinBrown. To make it more clear. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jq7WCsAsL6ENP8KYAAtddYlUX1yGWhh0/view?usp=sharing
There's the all thing. Some curve can be too long, for example colored it purple. And i have to cut a part that too cloose. In enter i've got only X and Y lists. 

About optimization, may be you have some ideas how to make algorithm faster than n^2.

Comment: @JonasH check plis comment above

Comment: Sweeping through the array of points on the curves deleting any point that can be accurately predicted from its immediate neighbours until there are no further improvements will be O(n.log(n)). Are XLine and YLine the two almost straight not quite horizontal lines bounding the "pipe". The diagram is very colourful but confusing to look at.

Comment: Remaer Douglas Peucker is `O(n log n)`, as most line simplification algorithms should be. But you should really improve the question to make it clearer, not  add a bunch of information in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `XLine` and `YLine` have just 2 points each we can try solving problem as follow.
Having a line which is drawn through two points `(ax, ay)` and `(bx, by)` we can write this line as an equation

```
A * x + B * y + C = 0
```

as (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422602/convert-two-points-to-line-eq-ax-by-c-0)

```
A = ay - by
B = bx - ax
C = ax * by - bx * ay
```

Having the equation, we can easily compute distance from a point `(px, py)` to the line

```
DistanceSquared = (A * px + B * py + C) * (A * px + B * py + C) / (A * A + B * B)
```

Something like this:

```
LineCheck(...) {
  ...

  // Let use long to avoid integer overflow
  long ax = XLine[0];
  long bx = XLine[1];
  long ay = YLine[0];
  long by = YLine[1];

  long A = ay - by;
  long B = bx - ax;
  long C = ax * by - bx * ay;

  for (int i = 0; i < Xcurve.Count; ++i) {
    double px = Xcurve[i];
    double py = Ycurve[i];

    var d2 = (A * px + B * py + C) * (A * px + B * py + C) / (A * A + B * B);

    if (d2 >= deviation * deviation) {
      returnCurveX.Add(Xcurve[i]);
      returnCurveY.Add(Ycurve[i]);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but a little bit unstable)) Will try to fix. Result:
My (old) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pKdchaDJR_x8-wn5wikS0DmWSQtoxtKJ/view?usp=sharing
Yours (new) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1761M776MmY6GSeCSDBwgalZMAWUqkB4x/view?usp=sharing